# Remove outliers while mapping one range to another?

Tags: c#, .net

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907134/map-an-unbounded-range-of-values-to-10-colors) on how to map a range between 0 and n to 0 to 9.

I use this solution and it works:

```
private int MapValue(int value, int n)
{
    int output = (int)Math.Round((10.0 / (n - 1) * (value - 1)) - 0.5, 0);
    if (output == -1) return 0;
    else return output;
}
```

Now I encountered another problem. I one example I have the range 0 to 1116. However most values or between 0 and 50 or maybe 0 and 100. So nevertheless most values are mapped to the same color. How can i avoid that such outliers tamper with my mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the outliers and then map them to the high or low values in the range.  There are many different ways to find the outliers.  [One simple way](http://www.ehow.com/how_5201412_calculate-outliers.html).  Search for "how to find outliers" and you'll find lots of solutions.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be a lot of calculation necessary :D