# Gradient line in SVG for Google map path

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I am interpreting GPS location data in google map, here i would like create a path with gradient which starts with red and ends with  orange

[this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) tutorial  has only a straight single color line as path

following code is responsible for path in gmap

```
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
 path: flightPlanCoordinates,
 geodesic: true,
 strokeColor: '#FF0000',
 strokeOpacity: 1.0,
 strokeWeight: 2
});
```

How can i change this to Gradient ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with help of @JerryDuwall 's answer i have done this

Of-course it is not a gradient but some how attractive than single color line

```
$.each(flightPlanCoordinates,function(k,v){
    i++;
    curLatLang  = new google.maps.LatLng(v[0],v[1]);
    if(prevLatLang == ""){
        prevLatLang = curLatLang;
    }else{
        var strokeColor = makeGradientColor({r:0, g:255, b:204}, {r:255, g:0, b:0}, ((i/coordinatelog.length)*100));
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: [prevLatLang,curLatLang],
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: strokeColor.cssColor,
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
        });
        prevLatLang = curLatLang;
        flightPath.setMap(map);
    }
}):
```

And `makeGradientColor` declartion follows

```
function makeGradientColor(color1, color2, percent) {
    var newColor = {};
    function makeChannel(a, b) {
        return(a + Math.round((b-a)*(percent/100)));
    }
    function makeColorPiece(num) {
        num = Math.min(num, 255);   // not more than 255
        num = Math.max(num, 0);     // not less than 0
        var str = num.toString(16);
        if (str.length < 2) {
            str = "0" + str;
        }
        return(str);
    }
    newColor.r = makeChannel(color1.r, color2.r);
    newColor.g = makeChannel(color1.g, color2.g);
    newColor.b = makeChannel(color1.b, color2.b);
    newColor.cssColor = "#" + 
                        makeColorPiece(newColor.r) + 
                        makeColorPiece(newColor.g) + 
                        makeColorPiece(newColor.b);
    return(newColor);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `interpolate` method within the Geometry library (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) to get `x` positions along the straight-line path (I'm assuming you're dealing with straight lines). This would allow you to construct `x-1` polylines. You could then generate colors within a red-orange gradient (refer to [Generate colors between red and green for an input range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849308/generate-colors-between-red-and-green-for-an-input-range)) and assign them to the strokeColor of each of your `x-1` polylines.

Increase `x` to get a more subtle gradient.