# css adjusting color to a value

Tags: html, css

I've got the following span:

```
<span><b class="colored">' + this.my.points_gp + '</b></span>
```

The `this.my.points_gp` can be a value between -12 and 80.
Now I need to define the "colored" class. What I need is to color the `this.my.points_gp` taking into account its value.

- If it's -12 must be very red.
- If it's 0 must be orange.
- If it's 20 must be light green.
- If it's 80 must be super green.

The thing is that values between the ranges should have different color code. I mean, 70 must be greener than 40 that must be green but lighter. -6 must be an intermediate between red and orange cause it's in the middle of the very red (-12) and the orange (0) and so on...

I'll try to explain myself better: I need 92 different colors and assign them gradually taking into account the base colors that I gave. Sorry for my english it is not my home language.

I don't know if this is possible... maybe in javascript and not in plain css?

Comment: what is "skiptranslate"? is it class or id?

Comment: don't mind about it, i editted the code and deleted it

Comment: Do you need like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849308/generate-colors-between-red-and-green-for-an-input-range?

Comment: yes, somehting like that!!

Comment: Check my answer. You may alter the ranges to tweak the color. For value 10, it produces pure yellow. For -12: red, 0: orange, 20: light green, 80: pure green.

Comment: right i'll test your solution soon, this seems the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function `colorize()` passing the value `v` and it sets variables `R`, `G`, `B` with appropriate values of red green and blue for different values of `v`. Then using css selector changes (if this selector doesn't work, you can try jQuery, much easier) the text (or background) color of selected element.

```
function colorize(v){
    // v is the value passed, range = [-12, 80]
    var R = 0, G = 0, B = 0;
    if (v <= 0){
        low = -12, high = 0;
        R = 255;
        G = 0 + Math.floor((150 - 0)*(v - low)/(high - low));
        B = 0;
    }
    else if (v >= 20){
        low = 20, high = 80;
        R = 150 - Math.floor((150 - 0)*(v - low)/(high - low));
        G = 255;
        B = 0;
    }
    else {
        low = 0, high = 20;
        mid = (low+high)/2;
        if (v < mid) {
            R = 255;
            G = 150 + Math.floor((255 - 150)*(v - low)/(mid - low));
        }
        else {
            R = 255 - Math.floor((255 - 150)*(v - mid)/(high - mid));
            G = 255;
        }
        B = 0;
    }
    color = 'rgb(' + R + ',' + G + ',' + B + ')';
    // if you want to change text color
    document.querySelector("span b.colored").style.color = color;
    // or if you want to change background color
    //document.querySelector("span b.colored").style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

p.s: Initially wrote in python, so check for unbalanced braces by mistake, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only way it's possible is with JavaScript or with PHP code (Assuming you're coding with PHP).

Here's a clue with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("colored")[1].style.color = "red";
```

Hope this helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question have lack of information.. Hope you need below one:

```
if( this.my.points_gp >= -12 && this.my.points_gp < 0 ) {
    <span class="very_red skiptranslate"><b>' + this.my.points_gp + '</b></span>
}
else if( this.my.points_gp >= 0 && this.my.points_gp < 20 ) {
   <span class="orange skiptranslate"><b>' + this.my.points_gp + '</b></span>
}
else if( this.my.points_gp >= 20 && this.my.points_gp < 80 ) {
   <span class="light_green skiptranslate"><b>' + this.my.points_gp + '</b></span>
}
else {
   <span class="super_green skiptranslate"><b>' + this.my.points_gp + '</b></span>
}
```

Comment: this code only displays 4 colors, i need to display 92 diferent colors adjusting th color gradually inside the ranges

Answer (score 0):

I'd add an ID to the span, remove the  tag (replacing it by font-weight:bold), so that it would be this way:

```
.colored{
    font-weight:bold;
    //other rules you may have
}

<span id="myId" class="colored">' + this.my.points_gp + '</span>
```

Then using javascript I'd add a class to change the color:

```
if( this.my.points_gp >= -12 && this.my.points_gp < 0 ) {
    document.getElementById("myId")[1].style.color = "red";
}
else if( this.my.points_gp >= 0 && this.my.points_gp < 20 ) {
   document.getElementById("myId")[1].style.color = "orange";
}
else if( this.my.points_gp >= 20 && this.my.points_gp < 80 ) {
   document.getElementById("myId")[1].style.color = "lightgreen";
}
else {
   document.getElementById("myId")[1].style.color = "darkgreen";
}
```