# Assign color (of Leaflet CircleMarker) to range of values

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I made a leaflet map showing CircleMarkers with Popups. They're colored depending on when the house they're standing for was built. (I am sorry, my English is horrible). Here's the link to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/marielouisejournocode/p2pL3r49/2/ 
As you can see, I set the color as follows

```
var colors = {
        1966: 'green',
        1960: 'yellow',
        1952: 'orange',
        1951: 'red'
    };
```

So js isn't my "native" programming language. In R I can assign a color to a range of numbers like `c(1950, 1960)` which would be all the numbers from 1950 to 1960 and the assignment would still work. I don't know how to get this range in js AND I don't know if I can assign a color to a range of numbers in it. I want to visualize all available construction years (I guess starting with the end of the second world war cause Dortmund got pretty destroyed) and it would be great if I won't have to assign each year one by one to 6 or so different colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your desired result is to assign a given color to your Circle Marker depending on the year property of your features (houses), but a range of years may receive the same color for simplicity (so you need just a couple of colors instead of one per year).

In that case, you have many ways to inspect the year and determine the appropriate color. An example would be in the [Leaflet Chloropleth map tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) (see "Adding Some Color" section)

```js
function getColor(d) {
  return d >= 1966 ? 'green' : // Means: if (d >= 1966) return 'green' else…
    d >= 1960 ? 'black' : // if (d >= 1960) return 'black' else etc…
    d >= 1952 ? 'red' :
    d >= 1940 ? 'orange' : // Note that numbers must be in descending order
    'grey';
}

// […]

L.circleMarker([place.lon, place.lat], {
  color: getColor(place.constructdate), // you can call the getColor function
  fillColor: getColor(place.constructdate),
  fillOpacity: 0.5
})
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p2pL3r49/3/

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function to do this:

```
function getRange(start, end) {
  var range = [];

  for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
    range.push(i);
  }

  return range;
}

var years = getRange(1950, 1961); // [1950,..., 1960]
```

If you're willing to use a utility library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can do this in one line:

```
var years = _.range(1950, 1961); // [1950,...,1960]
```

As for the colors, there are many ways to interpolate. There is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11850303/4230590)